# Find Microsoft Office 2013 install details with C#

Tags: c#, registry, office-2013

I have tried using ManagementObjectSearcher( "Select * from Win32_Product" ) and looking in the various "Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" registry keys but I cannot locate the office 2013 home and business information problematically using C# (even though I can see it in the registry using RegEdit).

I can, however, detect previous versions of office (e.g. 2003) using both methods

Please can someone point me in the right direction.

I have tried on machines using Windows 8 and Server 2008 R2 Versions of windows OS.

Many thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0):

This is because you run application as 32bit, but Office is listed on 64bit registry branch. You can't access it from .NET 2.0 alone (it's possible in the newest version).
You have to use Wow64 view.

The code that just works (on .NET 2.0).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            List<string> software = GetInstalledSoftware();
            // some entries will be duplicated!!!
        }

    public static List<string> GetInstalledSoftware()
    {
        const string KEY = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        list.AddRange(GetInstalledSoftwareFromHive(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, KEY, false));
        list.AddRange(GetInstalledSoftwareFromHive(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, KEY, true));
        list.AddRange(GetInstalledSoftwareFromHive(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, KEY, false));
        list.AddRange(GetInstalledSoftwareFromHive(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, KEY, true));


        return list;
    }

    private static List<string> GetInstalledSoftwareFromHive(RegistryHive hive, string keyAddress, bool use64)
    {
        uint main = 0;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            uint err = Win32Registry.RegOpenKeyEx(unchecked((uint)hive), keyAddress, 0,
                Win32Registry.RegSAM.Read | Win32Registry.RegSAM.EnumerateSubKeys | (use64 ? Win32Registry.RegSAM.WOW64_64Key : Win32Registry.RegSAM.WOW64_32Key),
                out main);

            if (err != 0) throw new Exception();

            string[] names = GetSubkeysNames(main);

            if (names == null) throw new Exception();

            foreach (string subkeyName in names)
            {
                uint sub = 0;

                try
                {
                    err = Win32Registry.RegOpenKeyEx(main, subkeyName, 0, Win32Registry.RegSAM.Read, out sub);
                    if (err != 0) continue;                        

                    string name = GetValueAsString(sub, "DisplayName");
                    if (name == null) continue;

                    list.Add(name);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (sub != 0)
                        Win32Registry.RegCloseKey(sub);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (main != 0)
                Win32Registry.RegCloseKey(main);
        }

        return list;
    }

    internal static string[] GetSubkeysNames(uint hMainKey)
    {
        uint numSubKeys;
        uint errorCode = Win32Registry.RegQueryInfoKey(hMainKey, null, 0, 0, out numSubKeys, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (errorCode != 0) return null;

        string[] names = new string[numSubKeys];

        for (uint i = 0; i < numSubKeys; i++)
        {
            uint maxKeySize = 1024;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((int)maxKeySize);
            long writeTime;

            errorCode = Win32Registry.RegEnumKeyEx(hMainKey, i, sb, ref maxKeySize, 0, 0, 0, out writeTime);

            if (errorCode != 0) break;

            names[i] = sb.ToString();
        }

        return names;
    }

    internal static string GetValueAsString(uint hSubkey, string valueName)
    {
        RegistryValueKind subkeyKind = RegistryValueKind.String;
        StringBuilder subkeyValueText = new StringBuilder((int)1024);
        uint subKeyValueSize = (uint)subkeyValueText.Capacity;

        uint errorCode = Win32Registry.RegQueryValueEx(hSubkey, valueName, 0, ref subkeyKind, subkeyValueText, ref subKeyValueSize);

        if (errorCode != 0) return null;

        return subkeyValueText.ToString();
    }

    internal static class Win32Registry
    {
        internal const uint REG_BINARY = 3;
        internal const uint REG_SZ = 1;
        internal const uint REG_DWORD = 4;

        [Flags]
        public enum RegOption
        {
            NonVolatile = 0x0,
            Volatile = 0x1,
            CreateLink = 0x2,
            BackupRestore = 0x4,
            OpenLink = 0x8
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum RegSAM : uint
        {
            QueryValue = 0x0001,
            SetValue = 0x0002,
            CreateSubKey = 0x0004,
            EnumerateSubKeys = 0x0008,
            Notify = 0x0010,
            CreateLink = 0x0020,
            WOW64_32Key = 0x0200,
            WOW64_64Key = 0x0100,
            WOW64_Res = 0x0300,
            StandardRightsRead = 0x00020000,
            Read = 0x00020019,
            Write = 0x00020006,
            Execute = 0x00020019,
            AllAccess = 0x000f003f
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint RegCloseKey(
            uint hKey);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint RegCreateKeyEx(
            uint hKey,
            string lpSubKey,
            int Reserved,
            string lpClass,
            RegOption dwOptions,
            RegSAM samDesired,
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
            out uint phkResult,
            IntPtr lpdwDisposition);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint RegQueryValueEx(
            uint kHey,
            string lpValueName,
            int lpReserved,
            ref Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind lpType,
            StringBuilder lpData,
            ref uint lpcbData
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint RegQueryValueEx(
            uint kHey,
            string lpValueName,
            int lpReserved,
            ref Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind lpType,
            ref uint lpData,
            ref uint lpcbData
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint RegSetValueEx(
            uint hKey,
            string lpValueName,
            uint Reserved,
            uint dwType,
            [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] lpData,
            uint cbData);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint RegDeleteValue(
            uint hKey,
            string lpValueName);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint RegDeleteKey(
            uint hKey,
            string lpSubKey);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint RegOpenKeyEx(
            uint hKey,
            string lpSubKey,
            uint ulOptions,
            RegSAM samDesired,
            out uint phkResult);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegEnumKeyEx")]
        internal extern static uint RegEnumKeyEx(uint hkey,
            uint index,
            StringBuilder lpName,
            ref uint lpcbName,
            uint reserved,
            uint lpClass,
            uint lpcbClass,
            out long lpftLastWriteTime);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegQueryInfoKey", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        internal extern static uint RegQueryInfoKey(
            uint hkey,
            StringBuilder lpClass,
            uint lpcbClass,
            uint lpReserved,
            out uint lpcSubKeys,
            uint lpcbMaxSubKeyLen,
            uint lpcbMaxClassLen,
            uint lpcValues,
            uint lpcbMaxValueNameLen,
            uint lpcbMaxValueLen,
            uint lpcbSecurityDescriptor,
            uint lpftLastWriteTime);

    }
}
}
```